# Integration with square root in denominator

Tags: calculus, integration

I am honestly embarrassed to ask this because i feel like i should know how to do this but:
$
\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{2x-1}}dx
$
Try to use u-substitution please

Comment: Try this substitution: $u=2x-1$ and thus $x=(1/2)(u+1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substitute $u=2x-1, du = 2dx$ so that you get

$$\int \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2x-1}} \, dx = \frac12\int\frac{u+1}{2\sqrt{u}}\, du = \frac12\int\frac{\sqrt{u}}{2} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}\, du.$$

Do you see how to proceede?

Comment: yes i do, thank you haha, seems to be a little tricky

Answer (score 1):

Another substitution you could use is $u=\sqrt{2x-1}$, so $x=\frac{1}{2}(u^2+1)$ and $dx=u du$.

This gives $\displaystyle\int\frac{\frac{1}{2}(u^2+1)}{u} u du=\frac{1}{2}\int(u^2+1) du=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{3}u^3+u\right]+C$

$\displaystyle\hspace{.5 in}=\frac{1}{6}(2x-1)^{3/2}+\frac{1}{2}(2x-1)^{1/2}+C$